# Difference between username-# and username=# in psql shell?

Tags: postgresql, psql

The user comes up usually in the form `username=#` in the console once you enter `psql` into the terminal. But then I noticed it said `username-#` where the equal sign was replaced with a hyphen but it still seemed to perform the same way.

I know it's a simple question but I'd still like to know. Does this change in symbol mean anything in particular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not username, it's the name of the database you're connected to. Usually each user has a private database, and `psql` connects to it by default.

The `-` means you're in the middle of writing an SQL query, or "ending semicolon missing":

```
test=# select 1+1
test-# ;
 ?column? 
----------
        2
(1 row)
```

Also, when you have unmatched delimiters, those are shown:

```
test=# select (1+1
test(# )
test-# ;
 ?column? 
----------
        2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Good answer, except I wouldn't say that typically each user has its own private database.

Comment: It is also displayed after a comment block (`/* comment */`), and you can either close the statement (`;`) or run the next query directly.