# I'm trying to import a SQL backup file but I keep getting an error

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to import a SQL backup file but I keep getting the error

```
todolist-# psql todolist < C:\Users\ojadi\Documents\todolist2.sql
invalid command \Users
Try \? for help.
todolist-#
```

Comment: Are you in powershell or... ? The windows path is throwing me with that `<` redirect.

Comment: @JNevill I am in SQL Shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a command you give in UNIX shell, not a command you give in `psql`. Since it seems you already have `psql` running, you can run the file using command

`\i C:\Users\ojadi\Documents\todolist2.sql`

Note that your prompt `todolist-#` indicates you are in the middle of writing a command in `psql`. See [my answer to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745919/difference-between-username-and-username-in-psql-shell/62746025)

Comment: Thanks but i get an error access denied

Comment: Maybe the user you use to run your `psql` does not have access to that file? Of course you can run the original command (the one starting with `psql`) from your normal OS shell. I haven't used Windows for 10 years so I don't know how you start a shell there :)